# unsatisfied dependency exception at @EnableBatchProcessing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying out Spring Batches to run details in MySQL database, I did some debugging but I just cannot seem to get pass the error at @EnableBatchProcessing...

I did a thorough search on what may be my error and what I may have done wrong but to no avail... what I think may be the problem is the dependency errors? But I've tried installing different versions/dependencies but it just comes up with more errors... Please advice   T.T

This is my complete console error shown...

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2018-11-21 15:21:00.581  INFO 38312 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on EUNICEHAN with PID 38312 (C:\Users\Eunice\Downloads\SpringBatchScheduler\SpringBatch5\target\classes started by Eunice in C:\Users\Eunice\Downloads\SpringBatchScheduler\SpringBatch5)
2018-11-21 15:21:00.596  INFO 38312 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2018-11-21 15:21:03.847  WARN 38312 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBatchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
2018-11-21 15:21:03.894  INFO 38312 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-21 15:21:03.955 ERROR 38312 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBatchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:605) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a.jobRepository(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a.CGLIB$jobBuilders$6(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$36366ee5.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a.jobBuilders(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/runtime/JobInstance
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3119) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2268) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.findDefinedEqualsAndHashCodeMethods(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:133) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:122) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:113) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.createLazyProxy(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.jobRepository(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:67) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a.CGLIB$jobRepository$5(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$36366ee5.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29ded91a.jobRepository(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.batch.runtime.JobInstance
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
    ... 84 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my DemoApplication...

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SpringBatchConfig.java");

        logger.info("starting project...");

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        logger.info("done processing");


    }
}
```

My SpringBatchConfiguration class...

```
    @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
//
    @Bean
    public static DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/custdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");

        try {
            String decryptedPassword = aes.decrypt("au4/MawRFvwOri4zWDMsPQ==");
            dataSource.setPassword(decryptedPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {logger.info(e.getMessage());}

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And finally my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.batch.runtime.JobInstance` means you have a dependency resolution issue and the JSR-352 jar is not in your classpath. I would recommend to use the `spring-boot-starter-batch` and let spring boot manage dependencies instead of manually importing `spring-batch-core` and `spring-batch-infrastrucutre` and set their version to 4.1.0.

You need to:

- remove `spring-batch-core` and `spring-batch-infrastrucutre` and replace them with `spring-boot-starter-batch` (without specifying the version, Spring Boot will import the right version)
- In your `SpringBatchConfig`, you autowire the datasource and you define it as a bean at the same time. While this is not an issue, I don't see why you need to autowire the datasource in this class, so you can try to remove `@Autowired public DataSource dataSource;` and make the `@Bean public static DataSource dataSource()` **non** static.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added this in my code but i started to have "failed to read artifact descriptor" error, that was why I used "mvn install" to install directly into my file : <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId> </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

add @EnableBatchProcessing on the Main Application class "DemoApplication"

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SpringBatchConfig.java");

    logger.info("starting project...");
.
.
.
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a JobBuilderFactory bean

```
@Bean
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory() throws Exception {
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory = new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository());
    return jobBuilderFactory;
}
```

Comment: So instead of @ Autowire a JobBuilderFactory, I declare a @ Bean like that in my SpringBatchConfiguration class? Could you please explain a little more on this code?